# AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter->onPerformSync takes too much time to be called

Tags: android, synchronization

I'm using AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter to synchronize some data from my Android's phone with a server. When the user logs in with the phone's application I perform a first synchronization so the user has all the data ready in the phone before he starts working with my application. I tested it with eclipse's emulator and it works fine, but when I test it on my phone the function onPerformSync takes too long to be called (like a minute or more).

This is the code I use in the Authenticator Activity:

```
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, false);
        params.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_DO_NOT_RETRY, false);
        params.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, false);
        ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, "com.pfc.authority", params, 30);
        ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, "com.pfc.authority", true);

        ContentResolver.requestSync(account,"com.pfc.authority",params);
```

The constructor of my AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter is called really fast, but then my application remains waiting for the sync to be complete, and like I said the onPerformSync function takes too much time to start, I don't know why my phone takes too long to call it.

This is the log (filtered for my application). I placed Log.d in the constructor and in onPerformSyn function:

```
11:47:49 SweetSyncAdapter: constructor
11:48:01 SweetSyncAdapter: constructor
11:48:36 SweetSyncAdapter: onPerformSync
```

I looked the full log (without filtering it) and there is no errors or warnings while executing my application, but I saw that there was another syncrhonization going on (music, calendar, etc.). Can this be the problem?

I tested it with two different ROMs (2.3.6 JVU and now ICS), and it's the same. Does anybody know why this happens?

PD: Right now I saw that the same happens with logout (I perform a syncrhonization when the user logouts), and the phone has been 5 minutes waiting for the onPerformSync to be called).

Answer (score 1):

After I created an account I request a sync with following lines.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_FORCE, true);
bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
ContentResolver.requestSync(account, authority, bundle);
```

I think the `SYNC_EXTRAS_FORCE` will help you